# Python program exits immediately after start

Tags: python, python-3.6

given the following code (in python):

```
import random
import sys
import collections

commandStr = ["addClan", "addPlayer",
              "clanFight", "getMinClan"]

SUCCESS = "SUCCESS"
FAILURE = "FAILURE"
INVALID_INPUT = "INVALID_INPUT"

ClanID = dict()
playersID = dict()
ClanScore = collections.defaultdict(list)
playersClan = dict()
LosingClans = set()

Clans_count = 0;
players_count = 0;


def initline():
    global ClanID, Clans_count
    inLine = "init 2 0 1"
    outLine = "init done."
    ClanID[0] = {}
    ClanID[1] = {}
    Clans_count += 2
    return inLine, outLine


# addClan clanID
def addClan():
    global ClanID, Clans_count
    clanID = random.randint(-2, 8)
    inLine = "addClan %d" % (clanID)
    outLine = "addClan: "
    if clanID < 0:
        outLine += INVALID_INPUT
    elif clanID in ClanID.keys():
        outLine += FAILURE
    else:
        ClanID[clanID] = {}
        Clans_count += 1
        outLine += SUCCESS
    return inLine, outLine

# addPlayer playerID score clanID
def addPlayer():
    global playersID, ClanID, ClanScore, playersClan, players_count
    playerID = random.randint(-10, 1000)
    score = random.randint(-10, 1000)
    clanID = random.randint(-2, 8)
    inLine = "addPlayer %d %d %d" % (playerID, score, clanID)
    outLine = "addPlayer: "
    if playerID < 0 or clanID < 0 or score <0:
        outLine += INVALID_INPUT
    elif playerID in playersID.keys() or clanID not in ClanID.keys():
        outLine += FAILURE
    else:
        playersID[playerID] = playerID
        if clanID in ClanScore.keys():
            ClanScore[clanID].append(score)
        else:
            ClanScore[clanID] = [score]
        playersClan[playerID] = clanID
        ClanID[clanID][playerID] = (playersID[playerID], clanID)
        players_count += 1
        outLine += SUCCESS
    return inLine, outLine

# getMinClan
def getMinClan():
    global ClanID, LosingClans
    inLine = "getMinClan"
    outLine = "getMinClan: "
    for Clan_id in sorted(ClanID):
        if Clan_id not in LosingClans:
            outLine += SUCCESS + " %d" % Clan_id
            break           
    return inLine, outLine

def sum_n_strongest(Clan, num):
    sortedClan = sorted(Clan, reverse=True)
    topNum = sortedClan[:num]
    Sum = 0
    for element in topNum:
        Sum += element
    return Sum

# clanFight clan1 clan2 k1 k2
def clanFight():
    global ClanID, ClanScore, LosingClans
    clan1 = random.randint(-1, 8)
    clan2 = random.randint(-1, 8)
    k1 = random.randint(-1, 10)
    k2 = random.randint(-1, 10)
    inLine = "clanFight %d %d %d %d" % (clan1, clan2, k1, k2)
    outLine = "clanFight: "
    if k1 <= 0 or k2 <= 0 or clan1 < 0 or clan2 < 0:
        outLine += INVALID_INPUT
    elif clan1 not in ClanID.keys() or clan2 not in ClanID.keys() or clan1 == clan2 or len(ClanID[clan1]) < k1 or len(ClanID[clan2]) < k2:
        outLine += FAILURE
    elif clan1 in LosingClans or clan2 in LosingClans:
        outLine += FAILURE
    else:
        sum1 = sum_n_strongest(ClanScore[clan1], k1)
        sum2 = sum_n_strongest(ClanScore[clan2], k2)
        if sum1 == sum2:
            if clan1 < clan2:
                LosingClans.add(clan2)
            else:
                LosingClans.add(clan1)
        elif sum1 < sum2:
            LosingClans.add(clan1)
        else:
            LosingClans.add(clan2)
        outLine += SUCCESS
    return inLine, outLine

def main():
    if len(sys.argv) < 3:
        print("Usage %s <lines>" % sys.argv[0])
        exit(0)
    lines = int(sys.argv[1])
    infname = "%s.in" % sys.argv[2]
    outfname = "%s.out" % sys.argv[2]
    functions = [addClan, addPlayer,
                 getMinClan, clanFight]
    with open(infname, 'wb') as infhandler:
        with open(outfname, 'wb') as outfhandler:
            inLine, outLine = initline()
            infhandler.write(inLine + "\n")
            outfhandler.write(outLine + "\n")
            while lines > 0:
                f = random.randint(0, len(functions)-1)
                func = functions[f]
                inLine, outLine = func()
                if inLine is not "":
                    infhandler.write(inLine + "\n")
                    outfhandler.write(outLine + "\n")
                    lines -= 1
            infhandler.write("quit\n")
            outfhandler.write("quit done.\n")


main()
```

This code should create a new file while I need to give as parameters `filename` and `numberOfLines`.
But, while I trying to run this script, opened to me a black window (like a cmd) and it's closed immediately.

How can I fix it? someone know what is the problem?

Note: this code written me in a file which his name is "Test.py" , and I trying to run it with this line command:  `python ./Test.py <Number of Lines> <Test Name>` (at least, I trying to do it while I double-click about "Test.py" but like that I said, the window closed immediately..

Comment: Strange, the "script opens a black window, then immediately closes" problem usually only occurs when you double-click on the script icon, not when you execute it from an already-open command prompt. Which I assume you're doing, since you're providing command-line arguments... Right? How _are_ you running your program?

Comment: You right, I double-click on the script icon (I'm sorry for the confusion because of the pressure).

Comment: Ok, so instead you should open a command window and enter `python ./Test.py <Number of Lines> <Test Name>`, just as you said.

Comment: Where is exists this a command window?

Comment: _Note: this code written me in a file which his name is "Test.py"_ Most code is written by humans, not vice versa. But hey, nice to meet you, machine-written human!

Comment: @Clijsters What? I talked about the code in my question..

Comment: @WantToKnowMath I can see the file is getting created. Try to check in the path where you execute the file. Else provide a path to the file where you want to save

Comment: @yogi How can I run this script in a command window?

Comment: @WantToKnowMath which machine are you using? If windows - type 'cmd' in run dialog and execute the python command whatever you were doing. If mac - use 'iterm'. I just gave this - `MacBook-Pro Desktop $ python try.py 5 tester`

Answer (score 0):

Follow-up question: Are you using an IDE, or are you trying to run this from the command line/command prompt?

First, check if the files exist after you run the program. It might just be that the program is running quickly enough that it only takes a couple milliseconds, and the command prompt goes away once the program terminates. If it does create a file, the program wouldn't outwardly notify you; look in your file directory and see if it did.

Second, instead of just calling `main()` at the end of your file, maybe try:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

and see if anything different happens. This bit of code is executed whenever the file is run as specifically as a script (as you're doing with the command `% python Test.py <num> <fname>`).

Comment: Well, that means it's at least running the script. That would be happening on the line `infhandler.write(inLine + "\n")`, probably. I think it's because you opened the file using `open(infname, 'wb')`. Try just `open(infname, 'w')` instead, and see if that works - the difference is that `wb` mean to open and write in *binary* mode, and `w` means to open and write in text mode - and python is having trouble converting your string to binary.